# "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:indowsystem32md.exe" does not exist."

Tags: terminal

I think this is because my terminal path is "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", with some sort of typo, which is why vs code thinks that "indowsystem32md" doesn't exist... I keep changing my terminal.integrated.shell.windows to "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", and saving the settings.json and restarting my vs code, but whenever i try to open the terminal it keeps sending me that error message in the title. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's your setting look like? Can you update your question and include the pertinent bit?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today, and the solution for that being to use forward `/` instead of `\`. So my path ended up looking like:

```
C:/WINDOWS/System32/cmd.exe
```

rather than:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```